# how to create a live search bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Beginner here, please bear with me!

How do I create a live search bar (searches as you type) that interacts with already existing hyperlink images?
Heres a Microsoft Paint image to explain what I'm trying to say: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXb4v.png

I really hope you guys know what I'm talking about, I found tutorials on how to create live search that displays results right under the search bar (kinda like a drop down menu) but I haven't found any tutorials that explained how to use the live search bar to interact with existing hyperlink images (narrowing down the number of images in the results).

Comment: This is exactly what you're looking for: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-filter-images/

Comment: I will check it out, MHakvoort. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Ok. Im sorry, wont do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your particular goals and libraries you'd like to use, different implementations will be best. The question is rather vague, so it's difficult to give advice to you.

Basically, your options are:

1. Redraw the image list from scratch whenever a different picture set matches your filter string.
2. Start by showing all the images. When the search string changes, hide the images that don't fit the search and show the ones that fit.

The second one seems to be more appropriate for your question and is simpler to implement, so I will provide an example for the solution here. Just HTML/Javascript, no libraries.

HTML:

```
<form id="filter_form">
  <p>Search:</p>
  <input id="filter" name="filter" type="text" size="40" onkeyup="filter_pictures();"></input>
</form>
<p>
    <img class="filtered" src="url1"></img>
    <img class="filtered" src="url2"></img>
    <img class="filtered" src="url3"></img>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
function filter_pictures() {
    var $i = 0;

    //Get the text we use to filter
    var $filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;

    //Get all images
    var $imgsCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('filtered');

    //For every image check if url has filter in it and hide/show as needed.
     for ($i = 0; $i < $imgsCollection.length; $i++) {
        if ($imgsCollection[$i].getAttribute('src').indexOf($filter) > -1) {
            $imgsCollection[$i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            $imgsCollection[$i].style.display = 'none';
        }
     }
}
```

Depending on your particular goal, you may make more events fire the filtering function (not just onKeyUp).

If you would go the re-drawing route, you can store the image urls in an array, check that array against the filter, then build the html including the images that matched and assign it to the innerHTML property of a div. You should fire it onkeypress the same way as in the example.